# Latency spike on Cassandra when adding nodes

Tags: java, cassandra, garbage-collection, ycsb

Recently I have been playing with Cassandra.
I have been experienced latency spikes when adding nodes to Cassandra while nodetool stream limits are set on all existing C* nodes.

To be specific, originally the cluster has 4 C* nodes and I am adding 2 additional nodes when the original ones are warmed up at 1200 s as shown in the figure.
The amount of data stored is 50 GB on these 4 nodes and the key size is 20 KB each.
Nodetool is used to set the 'stream limits' to 1MB/s.
YCSB is used to generate read dominant (90%) workloads at 80% of the maximum throughput that can be reach by these 4 existing nodes through out the scale up procedure.
The figures shows the output service latency from YCSB every 10 second.

[time vs. read latency on C*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWSZY.png)

Does anyone has some answers to the latency spike?
Maybe is the gc or compaction in the background?
Or just the bandwidth saturated, which does not seem so since I have set stream limits to 1MB/s?

Comment: You already mention some potential causes yourself. Have you measured those aspects?